# Broadcast Click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue where pop is getting blocked because of the following flow.

```
click on link->function a->function b->popup
```

I understand that Most browsers block popups, unless they were initiated from a user event, such as a click on a button or a link. Is it possible:

```
click on link->function a ->broadcast a click event -> function b ->popup
```

FYI: Pop up is `FB.login()` popup

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<a id='linkId' href='#' onClick='someFunction()'>link</a>


$('linkId').click();
```